# How can I manually plot a curve of two continuous predictor variables in separeted graphics?

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, non-linear-regression

I read some questions about this subject, but I couldn't find an answer.

I have 30 samples and my model is:

```
y ~ poly(x,3) + z
```

The result is:

```
           Estimate     SE     Z    P

(Intercept) -2.851  0.234   -12.173  < 0.0001
poly(x)1    -0.784  1.036   -0.758   0.449
poly(x)2     1.937  0.845    2.293   0.022 *
poly(x)3     2.754  0.768    3.587   0.0003 **
z            0.342  0.105    3.268   0.001 *
```

**First**, I've tried to plot the curve using `geom_smooth`.

a) `geom_smooth(method = "betareg", se=FALSE, formula = y ~ poly(x,3))`

b) `geom_smooth(method = "betareg", se=FALSE, formula = y ~ z)`

Then, I got these graphics: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSKNG.png But, in this case, I didn't consider the real model, but modeled the variables separately, which is probably a wrong way to show the data.

**Second**, I tried to use `visreg`, but it does not work with `"poly(x,3)"` in the model: "Error in poly(x, 3): 'degree' must be less than number of unique points". If I use `"I(x^3)"` it works, but it changes the model a little.

**Third**, I'm trying to use `plogis`, but I don't know how can I insert the parameter estimates in the function and then in the ggplot graph.

Comment: Hi Barbara, welcome to Stack Overflow. It will be much easier to help if you provide at least a sample of your data with `dput()` or if your data is very large `dput(data[1:10,])`. You can edit your question and paste the output. You can surround it with three backticks (```) for better formatting. See [How to make a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I think gridExtra can help you. since you create separate ggplot objects yourself (one for each graphic you want to obtain). Here are a few examples you can start with.

[Arranging multiple grobs on a page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/arrangeGrob.html)